# Add all constructor parameters as instance attributes to class in PyCharm

Tags: python, groovy, parameters, constructor, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm. I start defining a class:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
```

I want it to look like this:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

Using alt-enter I can get PyCharm to add a single field to the class from `__init__` but then I have to go back and do it again individually for each variable, which eventually gets to be annoying. Is there any shortcut that does them all at once?

Comment: It's a nice question but I don't think there is option for that. Mainly, because whenever you add a new parameter to `__init__`, PyCharm offers you assigning that parameter as attribute. But it also offers you to name attribute different from parameter. I think assigning one by one is intentional...

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm doesn't have a built-in [intention action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/intention-actions.html) to automatically declare and set all the instance variables from the constructor signature.

So the 2 main alternatives to implement this functionality would be:

1. Using an [External tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-third-party-tools.html).
2. Using a [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/template-variables.html) variables and functions.
3. (I suppose [a Plugin could be developed](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/pycharm.html), but would likely involve more work.)

Using an external tool has its own set of problems, see the answer to [PyCharm: Run `black -S` on region](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67345512) for a general idea of what it involves.

For the problem in this question a Live Template is probably the easiest to integrate. The main drawback is having to use *Groovy Script* (the list of Live Template functions offers the possibility of using *RegEx* - I think the former is a better approach.)

So using the following Groovy Script `test.groovy`

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher

// the_func = "    fun_name(a, b, c)"  // For stand-alone testing.
the_func = _1  // PyCharm clipboard() function argument.

int count_indent = the_func.indexOf(the_func.trim());  // Count indentation whitspaces.

def arg_list_str

def pattern = "\\((.*?)\\)"
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(the_func);

while (m.find()) {
    arg_list_str = m.group(1)  // Retrieve parameters from inside parenthesis.
}

// println arg_list_str
String[] arguments = arg_list_str.split(",")  // Splits on parameter separator.

def result = ['\n']  // Ends the constructor line for convenience.

for(arg in arguments) {
    arg = arg.trim()  // Remove whitspaces surrounding parameter.
    if(arg == "self")  // Skips first method parameter 'self'.
        continue
    arg = " ".repeat(count_indent+4) + "self." + arg + " = " + arg + "\n" 
    result.add(arg)
}

String joinedValues = result.join("")

return joinedValues
```

And setting the Live Template at `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Live Templates` as shown in the screenshot. Using the `clipboard()` function together with `groovyScript("c:\\dir_to_groovy\\test.groovy", clipboard());` from the [Predefined functions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/template-variables.html#predefined_functions). (Although the *Groovy Script* can be written on a single-line it's easier in this case to put it in an external file).

[image]

Selecting the line including indentation, copying to the clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>), and choosing the Live Template pressing <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd>

[image]

The declaration of the instance variables is generated (after pressing enter the indentation is adjusted.)

[image]

**End notes.**

The signature parser in the included *Groovy Script* is simplistic and only concerned with solving the problem in the question. With some research a complete signature parser is probably available that would handle complex type hints and default arguments. But for purpose of the example it works adequately.

Comment: Has anyone created the complete signature parser that would handle complex type hints and default arguments?

Comment: @Slazer I haven't found one. [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy) probably has such a parser. The problem is type hints have been changing drastically with every Python version, currently not even PyCharm linter analyzes type hints 100% right. So maintaining such a continuously changing parser is no trivial task. I wrote this answer as a proof-of-concept, if you find the parser integrating it would go along the steps in this answer.