# Is there a way to define keymap shortcuts for external tools depending on the file type, in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide, linter, black-code-formatter

One use case would be to have the `black` code formatter for python files, and the [`sqlfluff`](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/index.html#) code formatter for SQL files, and to use the same keyboard shortcut for both tools.

Currently, both are set up in `Preferences -> Tools -> External Tools`, following [`black` documentation](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/editors.html#pycharm-intellij-idea).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly no. You cannot assign one shortcut and invoke a different External Tool based on the file extension.

But you can workaround it pretty easily:

- You will need to have a single External Tools entry instead of the current two.
- Make a shell/batch script that will do the actual formatting (will call the actual formatter tool).
- Use that script as an External Tools command.
- In that custom script detect what extension the file has and execute the most appropriate formatter there (`black` for Python files and `sqlfluff` for SQL files).

Comment: To expand on the answer, this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67345512/) shows the steps to run black (the case of running the tool on a region of code instead of a whole file), with minor changes the example can be adapted to call different tools depending on the file extension.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to LazyOne advice, I wrote this small shell script to run either `black` or `sqlfluff` depending on the file extension:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

file_path="$1"
file_name=$(basename -- "$file_path")
extension="${file_name##*.}"

echo "Formatting file $file_path"
echo "With extension $extension"

if [ "$extension" = "py" ]; then
  /Users/alexandre/.local/bin/black "$file_path"
elif [ "$extension" = "sql" ]; then
  /Users/alexandre/.local/bin/sqlfluff fix -f --dialect postgres "$file_path"
else
  exit 2
fi
```

Make sure to change the paths to your actual installation paths (outputs of `which black` and `which sqlfluff`).

You can save the script in a file (e.g. `code_formatter.sh`), and make it executable:

```sh
chmod +x code_formatter.sh
```

Then configure it as an external tool in Pycharm settings, and don't forget the `"$FilePath$"` argument:

[image]

You can now define a single keyboard shortcut for the "my code formatter" external tool, that should work on both sql and python files.