# How to convert instance attributes to class attributes in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there a way in PyCharm to take instance attributes

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, s: str):  #instance attribute
        pass
```

and add them as class attributes?

```
class C():
    s:str  # class attribute

    def __init__(self, s: str):  #instance attribute
        pass
```

Comment: [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661996/add-all-constructor-parameters-as-instance-attributes-to-class-in-pycharm) with a little modification

Comment: Indeed what you showed in second example is not a class attribute.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary I think the attribute on the second line is in fact a class attribute.

`A class attribute is a Python variable that belongs to a class rather than a particular object. It is shared between all the objects of this class and it is defined outside the constructor function, __init__(self,...), of the class.`
dzone.com/articles/python-class-attributes-vs-instance-attributes

`A Python class attribute is an attribute of the class (circular, I know), rather than an attribute of an instance of a class.`
toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide

Comment: @Slazer `s` is only a class attribute when you assign something to it in the body of the class. But now that you only annotated `s`, it is not a class attribute. By specifying `s: str` you're saying that instance variable `s` inside `__init__` and `__new__` should be of type `str`. [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations).

Comment: @Slazer first define a class like : `class A: s:str` then try to access it's `s` attribute using `A.s` python says : _AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 's'_